# How to draw text in perspective view

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glm-math, freetype

I am new to fonts and based upon some web tutorials i have written code that works in orthographic view.

When i change my projection matrix from orthographic to perspective view the font disappears.

i would like the font to behave like other objects where i pass `model` matrix along with View and Projection matrix to determine the final position on screen.

How do i port this code to make it work in perspective view.

Do i need to make changes in `RenderText` function as it is currently based on screen position.

If anyone can show me any reading stuff which can help me with this or help me with the existing code which i have pasted ,  i would be highly thankful.

This is my header file

```cpp
#include <map>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include "texture.h"
#include "shader.h"
#include <ft2build.h>
#include FT_FREETYPE_H

// Holds all state information relevant to a character as loaded uing FreeType

struct Character {
    GLuint TextureID;
    glm::ivec2 Size;
    glm::ivec2 Bearing; // offset from baseline to left/top of plyph
    GLuint Advance;
};

class MyFont
{
public:
    // Holds a list of pre-compiled Characters
    std::map<GLchar, Character> Characters;
    // Shader used for TextRendering
    Shader TextShader;
    // Constructor
    MyFont(GLuint width, GLuint height);
    // Pre-compile a list of characters from the given font
    void Load(std::string font, GLuint fontSize);
    // Renders a string of text using precompiled list of characters
    void RenderText(std::string text, GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat scale, glm::vec3 color = glm::vec3(1.0f));

private:
    GLuint VAO, VBO;
};
```

This is the Vertex shader

```c
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec4 vertex; // <vec2 pos, vec2 tex>
out vec2 TexCoords;

uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
    gl_Position =  projection * vec4(vertex.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
    TexCoords = vertex.zw;
}
```

These are the function definitions.

```cpp
MyFont::MyFont(GLuint width, GLuint height)
{
    this->TextShader = ResourceManager::GetShader("TextShader");
    this->TextShader.SetMatrix4("projection", glm::ortho(0.0f, 
    static_cast<GLfloat>(width), static_cast<GLfloat>(height), 0.0f),     GL_TRUE);
    this->TextShader.SetInteger("text", 0);

    // configue VAO/VBO for texture quads
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &this->VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &this->VBO);
    glBindVertexArray(this->VAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) * 6 * 4, NULL, 
    GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(GLfloat), 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

void MyFont::Load(std::string font, GLuint fontSize)
{
    // First clear the previously loaded Characters
    this->Characters.clear();
    // Then initialize and load the FreeType library
    FT_Library ft;
    if (FT_Init_FreeType(&ft)) // All functions return a value different  than 0 whenever an error occurred
        std::cout << "ERROR::FREETYPE: Could not init FreeType Library" << std::endl;
    // Load font as face
    FT_Face face;
    if (FT_New_Face(ft, font.c_str(), 0, &face))
        std::cout << "ERROR::FREETYPE: Failed to load font" << std::endl;
    // Set size to load glyphs as
    FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(face, 0, fontSize);
    // Disable byte-alignment restriction
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    // Then for the first 128 ASCII characters, pre-load/compile their characters and store them
    for (GLubyte c = 0; c < 128; c++) // lol see what I did there 
    {
        // Load character glyph 
        if (FT_Load_Char(face, c, FT_LOAD_RENDER))
        {
            std::cout << "ERROR::FREETYTPE: Failed to load Glyph" << std::endl;
            continue;
        }
        // Generate texture
        GLuint texture;
        glGenTextures(1, &texture);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        glTexImage2D(
            GL_TEXTURE_2D,
            0,
            GL_RED,
            face->glyph->bitmap.width,
            face->glyph->bitmap.rows,
            0,
            GL_RED,
            GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
            face->glyph->bitmap.buffer
            );
        // Set texture options
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

        // Now store character for later use
        Character character = {
            texture,
            glm::ivec2(face->glyph->bitmap.width, face->glyph->bitmap.rows),
            glm::ivec2(face->glyph->bitmap_left, face->glyph->bitmap_top),
            face->glyph->advance.x
        };
        Characters.insert(std::pair<GLchar, Character>(c, character));
    }
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    // Destroy FreeType once we're finished
    FT_Done_Face(face);
    FT_Done_FreeType(ft);
}
```

Definition for `RenderText` function

```cpp
void MyFont::RenderText(std::string text, GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat scale, glm::vec3 color)
{
    this->TextShader.Use();
    // Activate corresponding render state  
    glm::mat4 model = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0));
    glm::mat4 view = camera7.GetViewMatrix();
    this->TextShader.SetMatrix4("model", model);
    this->TextShader.SetMatrix4("view", view);

    this->TextShader.SetVector3f("textColor", color);
    this->TextShader.SetMatrix4("projection", 
     glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f), (float)800.0 / (float)600.0, 0.1f, 100.0f));
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindVertexArray(this->VAO);

    // Iterate through all characters
    std::string::const_iterator c;
    for (c = text.begin(); c != text.end(); c++)
    {
        Character ch = Characters[*c];

        GLfloat xpos = x + ch.Bearing.x * scale;
        GLfloat ypos = y + (this->Characters['H'].Bearing.y - ch.Bearing.y) * scale;

        GLfloat w = ch.Size.x * scale;
        GLfloat h = ch.Size.y * scale;
        // Update VBO for each character
        GLfloat vertices[6][5] = {
            { xpos,     ypos + h, 0.0 ,     0.0, 1.0 },
            { xpos + w, ypos,     0.0 ,     1.0, 0.0 },
            { xpos,     ypos,     0.0 ,    0.0, 0.0 },

            { xpos,     ypos + h, 0.0,      0.0, 1.0 },
            { xpos + w, ypos + h, 0.0,      1.0, 1.0 },
            { xpos + w, ypos,     0.0,       1.0, 0.0 }
        };
        // Render glyph texture over quad
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ch.TextureID);
        // Update content of VBO memory
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->VBO);
        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(vertices), vertices); // Be sure to use glBufferSubData and not glBufferData

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        // Render quad
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
        // Now advance cursors for next glyph
        x += (ch.Advance >> 6) * scale; // Bitshift by 6 to get value in pixels (1/64th times 2^6 = 64)
    }
    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}
```

These are the Projections.

```cpp
glm::ortho(0.0f, static_cast<GLfloat>(width), static_cast<GLfloat>(height), 0.0f)

glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f), (float)width / (float)height, 0.1f, 100.0f)
```

Comment: *"When i change my projection matrix from orthographic to perspective view the font disappears."* Probably the text disappears, because it is clipped by the near plane of the view frustum. You've to draw the (text) geometry "behind" the near plane. Since the z axis points out of the viewport, you've to translate the text with in negative z direction where -z >= near. Note, this is just a guess, because you didn't provide neither the projection matrix nor the modelview matrix.

Comment: @Rabbid Thankyou very much for the kind help.Indeed this was the case.

Comment: Currently i had to scale my xpos and ypos values in the MyFont::RenderText function , please have a look at the function.

Comment: The problem now is the font appears but upside down.

Comment: Please have a look at the RenderText() function , is this the correct way to calculate the values for the VBO data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When i change my projection matrix from orthographic to perspective view the font disappears.

The text disappears, because it is clipped by the near plane of the view frustum. You've to draw the (text) geometry "behind" the near plane. Since the z axis points out of the viewport, you've to translate the text with in negative z direction where -z >= near.

> The problem now is the font appears but upside down.

The issue is caused, because in normalized device space (in the "view" the) bottom left coordinate is (0, 0), but in the texture image the top left is (0, 0).

Flip the v component of the texture coordinates to compensate that:

```cpp
GLfloat vertices[6][5] = {
  //  x         y         z        u    v
    { xpos,     ypos + h, 0.0,     0.0, 0.0 },
    { xpos + w, ypos,     0.0,     1.0, 1.0 },
    { xpos,     ypos,     0.0,     0.0, 1.0 },

    { xpos,     ypos + h, 0.0,     0.0, 0.0 },
    { xpos + w, ypos + h, 0.0,     1.0, 0.0 },
    { xpos + w, ypos,     0.0,     1.0, 1.0 }
};
```